# Is there a way to allow the launching of privileged pods only in certain namespaces?

Tags: kubernetes

Is there a way to allow only certain namespaces or users to launch privileged pods?  I need to launch a certain service in a privilege mode-enabled container but I don't want to grant this ability to all users.

Running `kubelet` with `--allow-privileged=true` seems to permit anybody to run a privileged container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, I don't believe this is possible. I think `PodSecurityPolicy` may eventually be the way to accomplish this, but right now, it is a non-namespaced object. Some of the work is still ongoing, and you can track it on Kubernetes [Issue #23217](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/23217).